# PySpark explode stringified array of dictionaries into rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with StringType column (`edges`), which contains a list of dictionaries (see example below). The dictionaries contain a mix of value types, including another dictionary (`nodeIDs`). I need to explode the top-level dictionaries in the `edges` field into rows; ideally, I should then be able to convert their component values into separate fields.

**Input:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

SPARK = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport() \
                    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    Row(trace_uuid='aaaa', timestamp='2019-05-20T10:36:33+02:00', edges='[{"distance":4.382441320292239,"duration":1.5,"speed":2.9,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":954752475,"nodeB":1665827480}},{"distance":14.48582171131768,"duration":2.6,"speed":5.6,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":1665827480,"nodeB":3559056131}}]', count=156, level=36),
    Row(trace_uuid='bbbb', timestamp='2019-05-20T11:36:10+03:00', edges='[{"distance":0,"duration":0,"speed":0,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":520686131,"nodeB":520686216}},{"distance":8.654358326561642,"duration":3.1,"speed":2.8,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":520686216,"nodeB":506361795}}]', count=179, level=258)
    ]

df = SPARK.createDataFrame(data)
```

**Desired output:**

```
    data_reshaped = [
        Row(trace_uuid='aaaa', timestamp='2019-05-20T10=36=33+02=00', distance=4.382441320292239, duration=1.5, speed=2.9, nodeA=954752475, nodeB=1665827480, count=156, level=36),
        Row(trace_uuid='aaaa', timestamp='2019-05-20T10=36=33+02=00', distance=16.134844841712574, duration=2.9,speed=5.6, nodeA=1665827480, nodeB=3559056131, count=156, level=36),
        Row(trace_uuid='bbbb', timestamp='2019-05-20T11=36=10+03=00', distance=0, duration=0, speed=0, nodeA=520686131, nodeB=520686216, count=179, level=258),
        Row(trace_uuid='bbbb', timestamp='2019-05-20T11=36=10+03=00', distance=8.654358326561642, duration=3.1, speed=2.8, nodeA=520686216, nodeB=506361795, count=179, level=258)
       ]
```

Is there a way to do that? I've tried using `cast` to cast the `edges` field into an array first, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the mixed data types.

I'm using Spark 2.4.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [from_json()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) with [**schema_of_json()**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json) to infer the JSON schema. for example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# a sample json string:  
edges_json_sample = data[0].edges
# or edges_json_sample = df.select('edges').first()[0]

>>> edges_json_sample
#'[{"distance":4.382441320292239,"duration":1.5,"speed":2.9,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":954752475,"nodeB":1665827480}},{"distance":14.48582171131768,"duration":2.6,"speed":5.6,"nodeIDs":{"nodeA":1665827480,"nodeB":3559056131}}]'

# infer schema from the sample string
schema = df.select(F.schema_of_json(edges_json_sample)).first()[0]

>>> schema
#u'array<struct<distance:double,duration:double,nodeIDs:struct<nodeA:bigint,nodeB:bigint>,speed:double>>'

# convert json string to data structure and then retrieve desired items
new_df = df.withColumn('data', F.explode(F.from_json('edges', schema))) \
           .select('*', 'data.*', 'data.nodeIDs.*') \
           .drop('data', 'nodeIDs', 'edges')
           
>>> new_df.show()
+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+-----+----------+----------+
|count|level|           timestamp|trace_uuid|         distance|duration|speed|     nodeA|     nodeB|
+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+-----+----------+----------+
|  156|   36|2019-05-20T10:36:...|      aaaa|4.382441320292239|     1.5|  2.9| 954752475|1665827480|
|  156|   36|2019-05-20T10:36:...|      aaaa|14.48582171131768|     2.6|  5.6|1665827480|3559056131|
|  179|  258|2019-05-20T11:36:...|      bbbb|              0.0|     0.0|  0.0| 520686131| 520686216|
|  179|  258|2019-05-20T11:36:...|      bbbb|8.654358326561642|     3.1|  2.8| 520686216| 506361795|
+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+-----+----------+----------+

# expected result
data_reshaped = new_df.rdd.collect()
```

Comment: this is really good! I am having a slightly complex schema compared to this. My schema is 
array<struct<html:string,passage_id:bigint,text:string,urls:array<struct<url:string,url_text:string>>>>. Can you suggest how do I explode this. The only problem here is I don't want the URLs to be exploded. They should remain as a string.

Comment: you will need to manually set up `schema = "array<struct<html:string,passage_id:bigint,text:string,urls:string>>"`, then use from_json and inline function, something like the following: `df_new = df.selectExpr("inline(from_json(data, 'array<struct<html:string,passage_id:bigint,text:string,urls:string>>'))")`.

Comment: I saw your post, with your example text, you need to change passage_id from `bigint` to `string`. also, the sample is a struct not an array, I suppose you are missing out something in that example text? @satishsilveri

Comment: I need the passage_id to be big int because I am gonna push it to DynamoDB. In my post, I mentioned above the example, the dataframe consist of doc_id and array of dictionary and each dictionary looks like that!

Comment: @satishsilveri, if passage_id is saved as string in the original text as it was quoted, you should use `passage_id:string` in schema definition. or from_json will not return correctly. you can typecast it to bigint later after it's exploded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221590/discussion-between-satish-silveri-and-jxc).