# explode an arbitrary amount of JSON fields from a nested structure within a PySpark Dataframe (Structured Streaming Data)

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm working with some streaming data within the Databricks Structured Streaming Environment via IoT & API devices.

my schema is as follows:

```
    root
 |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- idNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |-- publishTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- make: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partitionKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- properties_sys: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

my body column contains nested json that can be one or two levels deep

i.e

```
data = { 'id': {['device_1' : ...,
                'device_2' : ...]..}..}
```

or

```
data = {'id' : 1,
         'temp' : 28}
```

I have a few functions that help me derive what the strucTypes should be of each unique stream I have coming into my databricks environment but this is based on a static list that I need to define before hand in a config file.

if we imagine this IoT device was measuring the weather after running my functions I would get (this is the structure of the `body` column)

```
 schema = [StructField(humidity,FloatType,true),
 StructField(rainfall,LongType,true),
 StructField(timestamp,DateType,true),
 StructField(city,StringType,true)]
```

now to explode the nested column I would just manually use the following line of code :

```
parsed_df = df.withColumn("body", from_json("body", schema)).select(col('partition'), 
col('offset'), col('idNumber'),col('publishTime'),col('make'),col('partitionKey'),
col('properties'),col('properties_sys'),col('date'),col('body.*'))
```

which unnests my json perfectly, but since my IoT device mixes with some API data I may get a new field within my `body` column that has no `StructType` so I can't define the Schema manually before hand.

so my question is, is there a way to define dynamic `explode` or a method that anyone has employed to create a dynamic schema that I could possible store/use before hand?

Comment: spark 2.4+ has a function `schema_of_json` which might help if you are not doing this in row-level. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json

Comment: @jxc that looks promising, have you had any experience in using it?

Comment: you can fetch a sample JSON line from the first row of the batch: `sample_json = df.select('body').first().body` and then schema = spark.range(1).select(schema_of_json(sample_json).alias('schema')).first().schema to get the schema in DDL format which can then be used in from_json() function. one of my previous post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590112/pyspark-explode-stringified-array-of-dictionaries-into-rows/56591042#56591042.

Comment: in case there are dot, spaces etc in field names of any StructType column/fields, you might want to use `re.sub` on the schema string to enclose the field names with back-ticks.

Comment: @jxc awesome, why don't you add an answer? this is very close to my own custom solution which I actually exported 50 rows into Pandas to flatten the JSON and then create a schema based on the cols to explode.