# How to dynamically reference items in a JSON struct using pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyspark

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
root
|-- class_id: long (nullable = true)
|-- Spongebob-metadata: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- class-map: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 3: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 4: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to use the field `class_id` to look up items in `class-map`.

I can use the "getItem()" command with a string literal like so:

```
df.withColumn("class", col("Spongebob-metadata.class-map").getItem("0"))
```

but when I try to use getItem dynamically like this:

```
df.withColumn("class", col("Spongebob-metadata.class-map").getItem(col("class_id")))
```

I get the error:

> "Field name should be String Literal, but it's class_id#95812L;"

What's the best way to do this assuming that I won't always know how many elements are in the "class-map"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark explode stringified array of dictionaries into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590112/pyspark-explode-stringified-array-of-dictionaries-into-rows)

Comment: @ggeop.  Do explode the array and then do a where the two columns match?  Let me give that a try.